# Maven surefire, site and site-report.html

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-site-plugin

we run a lot of JUnit tests like this:

```
public static class Group1 extends AbstractTester {
    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        // Testmethod
    }
}
```

With several Groups. surefire-report yields a warning for each group that looks like this:

```
[warn] [XHTML Sink] Modified invalid anchor name: 'TestClass$Group1' to 'TestClassGroup1'
```

So its eliminating the "$". In the XML output this $ are still in like here:

```
<testcase time="0.158" classname="TestClass$Group1" name="testSomething">
```

When I know generate the html report with mvn site the links are not working. Because the anchors get a name without $ but the href have a $ in it resulting in not working links...

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? Facing the same here with "spaces" in the names of my "test cases"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an unnecessary internal warning of a Maven library.

"This is no problem for the generated HTML page since the sink implementation takes care of this."

See issue https://www.smartics.eu/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=710